# When running zynaddsubfx I see Damage("/part0/"). What does this mean?

Tags: command-line, midi

I have been using zynaddsubfx lately. To open, I use the terminal:

```
zynaddsubfx
```

Then I connect with Patchage. After I have connected everything, I go to zynaddsubfx and click on the Instrument tab on the top of the menu bar:[image: Zynaddsubfx] Then I scroll down to "show instrument bank". After I left click with the mouse on this menu, I see this screen:

[image: Instrument_Bank]

So far, so good. Right now in the terminal it looks like this:

[image: Terminal_1] But after I select an instrument I get this error, and shortly after I get a few xruns: [image: Terminal_2] How do I fix this error? I am not sure what it means. Thank you all in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As strange as it sounds, the "Damage" log doesn't report an error. This is the function name to describe a user interface update, in the Zynaddsubfx project, which is expected when you load an instrument.

In fact, this message has been commented out in [commit 229a](https://github.com/zynaddsubfx/zynaddsubfx/commit/229a227cbf2a8ac4c243c2c10a5dfdc00ce70bb9), so it won't appear if you use a release more recent than May 20 2016.